# The definition of arcsin.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inverse-function

In my text book, it is written that

Define **arcsin** as the inverse function of  $$\sin : \left[- \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right] \to \mathbb R.$$

But I think it is wrong. As far as I remember, functions have the inverse if and only if they are bijective.

$\sin : \left[- \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right] \to \mathbb R$ is not surjective. For example, there is no $x_0 \in \left[- \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right]$ s.t. $\sin (x_0)=2.$

Isn't it $\sin : \left[ -\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right] \to [-1, 1]$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Sure, that's true. Usually if $f:A\to B$ is a function and $A'\subset A$ is a subset such that $f:A'\to B$ is injective, then when we say "The inverse of $f:A'\to B$" or "the inverse of $f$ restricted to $A'$"we really mean the inverse of "$f:A'\to f(A')$". It's just one of those linguistic things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of arcsin is to restrict the domain and codomain of $\sin\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ to make it bijective, as you say. First of all, since $\sin$ has period $2\pi$ and image $[-1,1]$, we can immediately restrict our function to $\sin\colon(-\pi,\pi]\to[-1,1]$.

However, there is a slight problem here, that $\sin(x)=\sin(\pm\pi-x)$, so for instance, $\sin(\pi/3)=\sin(2\pi/3)$. Thus, we must further restrict our domain to $\sin\colon[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]\to[-1,1]$ (*this is best seen graphically*). It can be shown that this function is, in fact, bijective.

**Surjectivity:** clear.

**Injectivity:** Suppose $x,y\in[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$ is such that $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$. Then, $0=\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\cos(\frac{x+y}2)\sin(\frac{x-y}2)$ by the sum-to-product formula. Thus, $\cos(\frac{x+y}2)=0$ or $\sin(\frac{x-y}2)=0$.

If $\cos(\frac{x+y}2)=0$, then since $\frac{x+y}2\in[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$, we must have $\frac{x+y}2=\pm\frac\pi2$. However, this only happens when $(x,y)=(\frac{\pi}2,\frac\pi2)$ and $(x,y)=(-\frac{\pi}2,-\frac\pi2)$, respectively, and we are done.

On the other hand, if $\sin(\frac{x-y}2)=0$, then again since $\frac{x-y}2\in[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$, we must have $\frac{x-y}2=0$. We again have $x=y$, which is what was desired.